# How can one merge Windows File History Backups

Tags: windows-10, file-history

#### Background

I've had Windows file history configured to backup to a network folder for the past couple of years.

I now need more space than the company NAS can supply so I

1. told windows to stop using the network drive,
2. moved the *File History* directory from my NAS to an external HD,
3. and configured windows to use the external drive for file history.

When I use windows explorer to view the history of a folder, the earliest versions that show up are from when I reconfigured file history to use the new drive; versions that I copied from the network drive do not show up.

I've investigated and found that there are now two folders for my computer in the File History directory:

- `{My Ext HD}:\\FileHistory\{My username}\{My computer's name}\`
- `{My Ext HD}:\\FileHistory\{My username}\{My computer's name} (2)\`

Judging by the modification dates on these two folders, the current backups are all being stored in `{My computer's name} (2)`

### How can I access my older backup revisions?

- Can I simply merge these two folders, or will that mess up Windows?
- If I can't fully merge them, is there at least a way I could access revisions from the old folder?

#### Notes

- The old backups span Windows 8.1 and an upgrade to Windows 10
- They are very large backups so I'd like to avoid the trial and error approach of creating a copy of the *File History* folder (which would take over a day) and trying to merge the folders to see what windows does.

Comment: To put it simply: **You can't.**

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue by:
Navigating to 'Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > File History > Select Drive'.

Selecting the drive in the list of available drives (this presented a further list of available back-ups).

Selecting the original backup from the list - i.e. {My Ext HD}:\FileHistory{My username}{My computer's name}.

This doesn't merge the multiple versions but did allow me to target the original one.  I deleted the others.